# cakephp 2.x pivot table

Tags: cakephp, pivot, pivot-table, cakephp-2.x

I have a table as follows

Tablename :  tb_daily_call_reports

```
+------------+-----------+
| username   |  date     |
+------------+-----------+
| Peter      |  5/5/2014 |
+------------+-----------+
| Steve      |  5/5/2014 | 
+------------+-----------+
| Peter      |  5/5/2014 |
+------------+-----------+
| Peter      |  5/5/2014 |
+------------+-----------+
| Peter      |  5/6/2014 |
+------------+-----------+
| Steve      |  5/6/2014 |
+------------+-----------+
| Peter      |  5/6/2014 |
+------------+-----------+
| James      |  5/7/2014 |
+------------+-----------+
| Steve      |  5/7/2014 |
+------------+-----------+
| James      |  5/8/2014 |
+------------+-----------+
| Peter      |  5/8/2014 | 
+------------+-----------+
| Steve      |  5/8/2014 |
+------------+-----------+
| James      |  5/8/2014 |
+------------+-----------+
| James      |  5/8/2014 |
+------------+-----------+
```

What I would like to do is count the users in particular day and display the output as follows

```
+-----------+--------+---------+---------+
|           | Peter  | Steve   |  James  |
+-----------+--------+---------+---------+
| 5/5/2014  |   3    |   1     |    0    |
+-----------+--------+---------+---------+
| 5/6/2014  |   2    |   1     |    0    |
+-----------+--------+---------+---------+
| 5/7/2014  |   0    |   1     |    1    |
+-----------+--------+---------+---------+
| 5/8/2014  |   1    |   1     |    3    |
+-----------+--------+---------+---------+
```

Using SQL query I get the required result (for clarity username = user_detail_id)

```
SELECT date,
count(IF (user_detail_id = 'Peter', date, NULL)) AS 'Peter',
count(IF (user_detail_id = 'Steve', date, NULL)) AS 'Steve',
count(IF (user_detail_id = 'James', date, NULL)) AS 'James',
FROM tb_daily_call_reports 
GROUP BY  date;
```

I need to implement this using CakePHP 2.x.

Thank you!

Comment: please edit your question posting the SQL you want to obtain, and post the code you tried so far

Comment: People aren’t going to give you the code just because you asked. Try yourself. Post your attempts, and someone can guide you as to where you’re going wrong and help you improve, rather than just giving you a solution.

Comment: That looks like a simple query (`select user_detail_id, date, count(*) from reports GROUP BY (date, user_detail_id)`) with embedded display logic - is there a reason you're not handling how you want to dislay the data in the view instead of the db..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are in your `DailyCallReportsController`

```
// First I search for all the distinct usernames that I have in my table

$names = $this->DailyCallReport->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'fields' => array('DISTINCT DailyCallReport.user_detail_id'),
        'recursive' => -1
    )
);


// Then for every username I create a virtual field for my Model

$fields = array('date');

foreach($names as $record)
{
    $user_detail_id  = $record['DailyCallReport']['user_detail_id '];
    $this->DailyCallReport->virtualFields['user_'.$user_detail_id] = "COUNT(IF (user_detail_id = $user_detail_id, date, NULL))";
    $fields[] = 'user_'.$user_detail_id;
}

// Finally I do the query

$pivot = $this->DailyCallReport->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'fields' => $fields,
        'recursive' => -1,
        'group' => array('date')
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The query part is giving error.      SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS `DailyCallReport__40`, () AS `DailyCallReport__30`, () AS `DailyCallRepo' at line 1

Comment: I think that the problem could be related to the fact that the id are numeric (but in your question `user_detail_id` was a string!). I edited my post so that the indexes of the virtualfields array are tring and not numeric

Comment: Date field is not shown. How do I show date? I added date in field but it didn't work.

Comment: I edited. Anyway my code is just an example. I though you could manage how to modify it to add all the other fields you eant to show in your pivot

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, patience and code. :-)